# Move tinymce chunks of text inside editor

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Inside my tinymce editor, I have several non editable chunks of text which I would like to be able to move inside of the editor, but haven't been able to find a way.

In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG76u.png) you can see the chunks of non editable content that I would like to be able to move around as blocks.

**UPDATE WITH CODE:** Ajax call that return noneditable text to add to the editor

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?option=com_nautilus&task=addToEditor&format=json',//
        type: 'POST',
        data: ({id: id, parentid: parentid}),
        success: function(result){
            console.log("Success: add node to editor ajax call");
            console.log(result);
            var noneditablecontent = '<div id="'+result[0].id+'" style="border: 1px solid black;" class="mceNonEditable"><strong>'+result[0].title+'</strong>'+result[0].content+'</div><p id="~~"></p>'; 
            var content = getcontent+noneditablecontent;
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Error: add node to editor ajax call");
        }
    });
```

Comment: where do you want to move those blocks? can you show the complete html code?

Comment: I only want to move them inside of the editor. The final objective is for these noneditable chunks to be able to change their order inside of the text, as for now they are only added at the end and can only change this position if the user manually adds text afterwards.

Comment: where do you  want to move them - and how (button, drag&drop,...)? do those blocks have a class or other identifier with which you can identify them in the editor content?

Comment: I would like to drag&drop them in the editor. They can be identified with the same class="mceNonEditable" and they all have a unique id.

Comment: what about setting them editable before moving them and setting them non-editable afterwards?

Comment: This [link](http://imgur.com/5QZawhc) is what happens now when I try to move the topic 3 chunk around as if it were normal text. The div were topic 3 used to be is fixed and other text is inserted inside.